# Building issues with Cocoapods sample app for a framework

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm building an iOS framework and using Cocoapods to distribute it. The framework is able to build but in order to see it in action I need to run the code in a sample app. This sample app I have put in the frameworks workspace.

Everything works great except for when making changes in the framework and then running those changes in the sample app. What I have been needing to do in order to see my changes is,

1. Switch to framework target
2. Build framework
3. Switch to sample app target
4. Run sample app

As you can see that's a lot of steps which get tedious very quickly.

Another problem I have experienced with my setup is that if I create a new file in my framework, I will need to first do a `pod install` before seeing that file visible in my sample app.

Am I missing something in the setup steps? Maybe something [extra](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#install_bang) needs to be in the Podfile? Is this setup even possible to have without the constant switching of targets?

**Podspec**

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  ...

  s.platform      = :ios, '9.0'
  s.swift_version = '5.0'

  s.source_files = 'SomeFramework/SomeFramework/**/*.{strings,swift}'
  s.resources    = 'SomeFramework/SomeFramework/**/*.{xcassets}'

  s.test_spec 'Tests' do |ts|
    ts.source_files = 'SomeFramework/SomeFrameworkTests/*.swift'
  end

  s.app_spec 'SampleApp' do |as|
    root = 'SomeFrameworkSampleApp/SomeFrameworkSampleApp'

    as.source_files = root+'/**/*.swift'
    as.resources    = root+'/**/*.{storyboard,xcassets}'
  end
end
```

**Podfile**

```
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

platform :ios, '9.0'
workspace 'SomeFramework'

target 'SomeFramework' do
  project 'SomeFramework/SomeFramework'
  target 'SomeFrameworkTests'
end

target 'SomeFrameworkSampleApp' do
  project 'SomeFrameworkSampleApp/SomeFrameworkSampleApp'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that CocoaPods isn't able to properly handle the combination of Podfile with Podspec, or in other words, distributing a framework while also importing other frameworks.

My solution is to use [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) for the dependency frameworks and CocoaPods for distributing my framework.

This solution has a few additional steps needed for setup but it allows the development experience to remain as expected.